# Graphical performance improvement for Intel HD Graphics in 18.04

Tags: drivers, lenovo, intel-graphics, performance, optimization

I own a Lenovo Yoga 710 laptop with Intel Core i5-7200U processor integrated Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2).

The graphical performance in Ubuntu 18.04 running kernel 4.15.0-33 seems to be a bit choppy. The animations are not that smooth. Compared to Windows 10, it's quite a lot worse.

I have been reading about it and have found such terms as Vulkan and Mesa, but they seem to be outdated and Intel itself doesn't provide official drivers for Linux.

My question is: are there any ways to optimize and improve graphical performance for Intel graphics?

Comment: Try kde or xfce, gnome uses a ton of resources for graphics

Comment: @Panther that is most probably a good idea. The bad thing is I prefer gnome.

Comment: You can run this command- `sudo apt remove i965-va-driver && sudo apt install i965-va-driver-shaders va-driver-all beignet-opencl-icd mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils` and restart, though it probably won't help. These days Gnome is more heavy on resources than Windows. If you prefer polished but lighter (than Gnome) experience you can try KDE (Kubuntu). Though I am a Xfce (Xubuntu) user myself I'm amazed to see Kubuntu 18.04's low RAM usage.

Comment: Are you running with wayland or xorg/X11? Are you running lightdm or gdm3?